# Find a substring within a column using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can I search for a substring within a column of a csv file, for example in the file column I want to select the rows where the word "fog" is found, but there are rows where there are the words "rain, cold, fog" and also I want those rows to appear.

I was using the following code:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('weather_2012.csv')
 neblina = df[df['Weather'] == 'Fog']
```

But using that instruction the rows of the form "rain, cold, fog" are not shown, how can I do to show the rows of that style

Beforehand thank you very much

Comment: Use `.str.contains`: `df[df.Weather.str.contains('fog', case=False)]`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use that

```
 df = pd.read_csv('weather_2012.csv')
 neblina = df[ 'Fog' in df['Weather']]
```